# android device rotation

Tags: android, rotation, device

how can i get the rotation of the device in the four main orientations? and is there a corresponding event that i can capture?

also, is it possible to disable this rotation for my app?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explains how to get the size and orientation of the screen.
http://indyvision.net/2010/02/android-screen-size-orientation/

However, the device already changes its own behavior depending on the device orientation. For instance you can specify screen layouts dependent on the orientation, one for vertical and one for horizontal.

To prevent the Activity from rotating with the device, you can add android:screenOrientation="portrait" or "landscape" to AndroidManifest.xml for each Activity declared in your app.

Comment: thanks! is there also an event that i can capture when the orientation changes?

Comment: The Activity is reloaded when orientation changes. You can override the onResume() method and put code that needs to run on each orientation change in there.

Comment: Link in the answer no longer exists.